# Stomp Over Websocket - CONNECT data (unrecognised opCode)

Tags: php, sockets, websocket, stomp

So I'm having a problem while connecting to a STOMP server using PHP.
Basically

When I'm testing on this tool http://jxy.me/websocket-debug-tool/ Things are working totally fine.
But when I test in my PHP code, I just get that error from the socket then it closes :

```
<?php 
$sock = stream_socket_client("tls://myserver:443",$e,$n,30,STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT,stream_context_create(null));
$headers = "GET /connect HTTP/1.1" ."\r\n".
            "Host: myserver" ."\r\n".
            "Accept: */*" ."\r\n".

            "Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade" ."\r\n".
            "Upgrade: websocket" . "\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13" ."\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate" ."\r\n".
            "Sec-WebSocket-Key: tq0zioAk6zN/Fe/xxFm2Jg==" ."\r\n".
            //"Sec-WebSocket-Key: ". rand(0,999) ."\r\n".
             "\r\n";
fwrite($sock, $headers);

//STOMP CONNECT
$headers2 = "CONNECT\n" .
            "accept-version:1.1,1.0\n".
            "heart-beat:10000,10000\n".
             "\n\x00";
fwrite($sock, $frame_data);
//read socket ....
```

Connection to websocket is successful :

> HTTP/1.1 101    X-Application-Context: myserver-context,ssl:8088
> Upgrade: websocket    Connection: upgrade    Sec-WebSocket-Accept:
> O5S7w6CwTldci16ctcWlN4A9leE=    Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:
> permessage-deflate    Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0,
> must-revalidate    Pragma: no-cache    Expires: 0 Date: Wed, 31 Mar
> 2021 17:32:40 GMT    Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;
> includeSubDomains; preload;    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> Referrer-Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade    X-Frame-Options:
> SAMEORIGIN    X-XSS-Protection: 1;mode=block    Feature-Policy:
> vibrate self;

But it gets closed after sending stomp CONNECT

> "�?�A WebSocket frame was sent with an unrecognised opCode of [3]"

OR

> The client frame set the reserved bits to [5] for a message with opCode [3] which was not supported by this endpoint

Not really sure what this error message is. It's probably related to my usage of protocol (STOMP or Websocket). However, I'm unable to find any reason or clue.

Any idea ?

Comment: It looks like you assume that Websockets are just sockets with some initial GET - they are not. There is an initial bidirectional handshake and there is a message framing, which depends on information from the initial handshake. For more information please refer to the [Websocket standard](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6455).

Comment: The initial GET request was for (Upgrading) it to Websocket. That should be good for the handshake ( Sec-WebSocket-Key + Sec-WebSocket-Accept). 
That's because PHP / Apache cant work with WSS out of the box, if I'm not mistaken. Don't you think so ? @SteffenUllrich

Comment: Again, Websockets are not simply sockets. Messages in Websockets need to be framed in a protocol specific way and in the framing also information from the handshake involved. You simply don't follow the Websockets standard in what you do and your problems are a result of this. So please study the actual standard instead of making wrong assumptions.

Comment: That's right, thank you sir for pointing that out! @SteffenUllrich